# FY vs last FY Cognos 11

Tags: cognos

I am looking to generate report in Cognos 11 for attended appointments for this FY vs last FY for the same time frame. For example of I am running report on 1st June 2021, I should get data for sum of appointments of April and May 2021 and sum of appointments of April and May 2020.
Please let me know how can I set the date filter.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share more of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any context.  There are many ways to do this.  Just providing a filter expression won't work because I don't know what the rest of your report looks like.

Describing such a general solution for Cognos in plain text is not simple.  I'll also assume that, since you are using Cognos, the database structure is a star schema containing a time dimension with columns named [FiscalYear] and [FiscalMonthNumber] that are integers.  Also, that your fiscal year runs from January 1 to December 31.

Using Cognos functions:

```
[FiscalYear] * 100 + [FiscalMonthNumber]
 between 
_year(_add_months(current_date, -2)) * 100 + 
_month(_add_months(current_date, -2))
 and 
_year(_add_months(current_date, -1)) * 100 + 
_month(_add_months(current_date, -1))

or

[FiscalYear] * 100 + [FiscalMonthNumber] + 100
 between 
_year(_add_months(current_date, -2)) * 100 + 
_month(_add_months(current_date, -2))
 and 
_year(_add_months(current_date, -1)) * 100 + 
_month(_add_months(current_date, -1))
```

Using Cognos macros:

```
[FiscalYear] * 100 + [FiscalMonthNumber]
 between 
#timestampMask (_add_months($current_timestamp, -2), 'yyyymm')#
 and 
#timestampMask (_add_months($current_timestamp, -1), 'yyyymm')#

or 

[FiscalYear] * 100 + [FiscalMonthNumber] + 100
 between 
#timestampMask (_add_months($current_timestamp, -2), 'yyyymm')#
 and 
#timestampMask (_add_months($current_timestamp, -1), 'yyyymm')#
```

The advantage of using the Cognos macro is that the value is computed once before sending to the database server, rather than the database server computing it for every row.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assumption that you have a data item like invoice date, etc, for the example this will be [Date] but you could change the filter to what makes sense based on your data items
2. The filter could use a date prompt with a parm i.e. PrmDate or use Current_date
   see explanation below

Filter should look like:

```
([Date] between [CurrentStart] and [CurrentEnd])
OR
([Date] between [PriorStart] and [PriorEnd])
```

Create some data items to make this a little easier

**Offset**, note: the offset allows you to change your starting month/period

This would be for January

```
extract(month, current_date) -1
```

This would be for April

```
extract(month, current_date) -4
```

**CurrentStart**

```
_first_of_month (_add_months(current_date, -[Offset]))
```

CurrentEnd, note: if you don't want a prompt, just swap ?PrmDate? with Current_date

```
 _add_months(?PrmDate?,-1)
```

**PriorStart**

```
_add_years([CurrentStart], -1)
```

**PriorEnd**

```
_add_years([CurrentEnd],-1)
```